# Adjusting symbology in layer file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, symbology

I have a layer file for a geology layer containing attributes for `Age`, `Rock Type` and `L_Code`. The layer has symbology defined using the `L_Code` attribute. But I want the same symbology applied using the concatenated `Age` and `Rock Type` fields. Each `L_Code` matches with exactly 1 `Rock Type` value and 1 `Age` value.

How can I do this?

See figures below.

This is what the original layer file looks like, defined using the `L_Code` attribute.

[image]

This is what I want the final legend to look like. The label column shows concatenated strings from both the `Age` and `Rock Type` fields.

[image]

Comment: Explorer `arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management`. this can help I guess

Comment: If the L_CODE links to unique combinations of Age and Rock type, then you already have concatenated symbology. Possibly L_CODE was created for software that does not support multifield symbology, but ArcGIS does. So is the question how to get the long description into the legend most efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to export the Attribute Table out to Excel / Spreadsheet program and run a VLOOKUP using the L_Code and text you would like the L_Code to present in the legend.

You can then add this new table to the map, and perform a Table Join between this table with the correct text and the original Geological Data. Creating a new field called "LEGEND" and copying the joined text from the joined fields into this new "LEGEND" field.

You can then apply the symbology you want using this field and update as is needed in future iterations.

Comment: Thank you for the response. 

"You can then apply the symbology you want using this field and update as is needed in future iterations."

Not sure how this can happen without the symbology that's already assigned being reset having to start over from scratch. I have the new table with the new field "Legend_Text" that has the text I want assigned to the symbology. However, the layer file already comes assigned to a column that existed pre-join.

Comment: I think you will have to start from scratch. If I am not mistaken you can change the symbology using a python script. Unfortunately I do not have access to my ArcMap to see. But a quick search of this site should give you some ideas.